# Working with windows shared file in ubuntu

Tags: windows, samba, read-only, active-directory, xls

We are using windows(8.1 & 10) and ubuntu(20.04) in our network environment. When we open a xls,word file in ubuntu which is already opened in windows it is not prompting as a read only and also we are encountering issues with date,month,year data in xls,xlsx files and it is mismatch with windows file.

Note(File server is windows 2012 r2 and we added ubuntu system to our domain using realm sssd)

Comment: Word on Ubuntu ?

Comment: same issue with word also

Comment: Please reply us if someone have answer for this..